# Count characters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, count

I'm starting to make some scripts in PowerShell but I have a problem.

I want to count the number of characters that someone introduce by keyboard. I'm trying this:

```
write-host $FC
$numcar = $FC.Count
```

But it always returns 1.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9):

Change your code to the following:

```
$FC = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter some characters"
$numcar = $FC.length
```

You need to use the `Read-Host` command in order to get input from the keyboard. So this code sets the `$FC` variable to the data inputted from `Read-Host` and then the variable `$numcar` is set to the amount of characters entered, or 'length'. You got this confused with 'Count'.